# Объеденить повторяющиеся поля в SQL в одно поле с условием

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql, sql-server

Есть таблица

```
Id | Date | Title      | Unique Id
 
1   2020    some title   1
2   2021    some title   2
2   2020    some title   3
```

Надо объединить все повторяющиеся по ID строки в одну (известно что будет отличаться только дата), при этом дату сделать формата (firstDate - secondDate). К примеру должен получится такой результат:

```
Id | Date        | Title      | Unique Id
 
1   2020          some title   1
2   2020-2021     some title   2
```

Comment: а если повторяться будут 3 значения? и какая версия СУБД ?

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло

```
STRING_AGG(Date, '-')
```